# Python Mock open when there are multiple with open

Tags: python, mocking

```
    def second():
        with open(path, 'r') as second_something:
            second_json = json.load(second_something)
    
    def first():
        second()
        with open(path, 'r') as first_something:
            first_json = json.load(first_something)
            
    
    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open, read_data='{"hello":"yes"}')
    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open, read_data='{"world":"no"}')
    def test_first(self):
        first()
        #doing asserting here
        assert(fist_json,{"world":"no"})
```

Writing a test case for "**first**" function and want to mock both "with open" statment, so wrote two @patch but both are getting **'{"hello":"yes"}**', instead of one getting '**{"hello":"yes"}**' and another **'{"world":"no"}'**. Having trouble with mocking this, please help me out.

Comment: How is `path` set in each case? If it's the same file being opened, why are you trying to make each function parse a different file content? I would refactor both functions to take an open file as an argument, rather than having each function open a named file itself.

Comment: Hey, sorry @chepner I was not clear path for both open are different.

Comment: That's not at all obvious, because you use the same (apparently global) variable for both, and it would be nearly impossible to change the value appropriately between `second` and `first` opening the file.

Comment: This is probably better addressed, as suggested in the documentation for `mock_open`, using an in-memory filesystem, which shifts the patch from the `open` function to the file being opened itself.

Comment: At the very least, you can patch `builtins.open` with your own function that can examine the path argument, instead of using `mock_open`.